# Why this program is compiling with gcc but not with g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Following Program compiles with gcc but not with g++, I am generating only object file.

This is prog.c:

```
#include "prog.h"

static struct clnt_ops tcp_nb_ops = {4};
```

This is prog.h:

```
#ifndef _PROG_
#define _PROG_

#include <rpc/rpc.h>

#endif
```

When I do:

```
gcc -c prog.c
```

That generates object code but,

```
g++ -c prog.c
```

gives error:

```
variable ‘clnt_ops tcp_nb_ops’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Where is definition of structure??? In C can we define a structure like this? In c++ i think it is not possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the definition of this struct in `clnt.h`:

```
typedef struct CLIENT CLIENT;
struct CLIENT {
  AUTH  *cl_auth;        /* authenticator */
  struct clnt_ops {
    enum clnt_stat (*cl_call) (CLIENT *, u_long, xdrproc_t, caddr_t, xdrproc_t, caddr_t, struct timeval);
    /* ...*/
  } *cl_ops;
    /* ...*/
};
```

As you can see, the `struct clnt_ops` is defined *inside* `struct CLIENT`. So the proper name for this type in C++ is `CLIENT::clnt_ops`. In C, however there is no such thing as nested structs, so it is visible as simply `struct clnt_ops`.

If you want to be portable you may add something along the lines of:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef CLIENT::clnt_ops clnt_ops;
#else
    typedef struct clnt_ops clnt_ops;
#endif

clnt_ops tcp_nb_ops = ...;
```

But I think that this type is simply not intended to be used directly by client code. Instead use whole `struct CLIENT` only.

Comment: Thanks that worked for g++, but if there is no such thing as nested structure in c, then should not it throw some error?

Comment: @Sumit: I didn't explain myself. In C you can define a struct inside another struct, but all the struct names will be visible at global namespace, as that is the only namespace there is. However, the variable defined with the inner struct will be a proper member of the struct.